# Defining a variable before the variable is written

Tags: bash

Currently, I have;

```
echo "Whats the year?"
read year
echo "Whats the Month you're running this for?"
read month

TARGET=`pwd`/"BLAH"$year$month"BLAH"
TARGET_888=`pwd`/"BLAH"$year$month"BLAH"
```

The output would be: pwd/BLAH201312BLAH for example. Is there any way I can use the variable, so define TARGET and TARGET_888 without using the echo's before this? I just want to make my code a lot neater and not have variables in the middle of my code.

Comment: In BASH, you can use `read -p"What's the year?" year` to get _rid of the echoes_, but you want to _not have variables in the middle of my code_. Variables are a central concept of coding, so I'm not sure what your issue it. Plus, your title is _defining a variable before the variable is written_ which seems to mean defining a variable when you need one. Can you clarify exactly what is bothering you with your program?

Comment: I would like the following format in my script if possible:

    TARGET="$PWD/BLAH${year}${month}BLAH"
    read -p"what is the year?" year
    read -p"what is the month?" month

Would there be a way to do this? Thanks for the response!

Comment: @user2939503: You cannot use variables before setting its values. You can use some placeholders to define a format and supply values later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid echo by using `read -p`:

```
read -p "Whats the year?" year
read -p "Whats the Month you're running this for?" month

TARGET="$PWD/BLAH${year}${month}BLAH"
TARGET_888="$TAGET"
```